# Outlook: Releasing COM objects retrieved using delegates

Tags: com, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Just for the sake of argument, let's say you are using the **Attachments** collection.  This collection implements IEnumerable.

What is going on behind the scenes if we were to do something like this?
Does each iteration of through the collection create an "AttachmentS" object that cannot be released?

```
  void SomeEventHandler( Attachments attachments, object args )
  {
      Outlook._Attachment attachment = attachments.First( x => x.Subject == "I like COM" );

     // do stuff
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachment);
  }
```

The call to **First** will iterate through the collection of COM objects.  Will it act like  **foreach** and cause COM references we cannot release?

Comment: It works like foreach, also uses IEnumerable which maps to the IEnumVARIANT COM interface.  I doubt it is obvious to the reader of your code why you won't release in the foreach loop but do in the for-loop.

Comment: @HansPassant:  Your observation is of course correct.  That was a silly mistake on my part.
I've updated the code a bit to use "MyInbox.Items" to illustrate my first point about not using the "foreach".    You said, it works like foreach.  Would it be correct to infer from your response that using the "First" method along with the delegate would cause "AttachmentS" objects to be created that cannot be Released?

Comment: @HansPassant:  I've updated the code. I noticed that my attempt at being thorough was just a lot of overhead.  Hopefully my post is clearer now.

Comment: @HansPassant Don't waste your time with this.  I'd been working with Generics and lambda expressions through the night, when suddenly I had the bright idea of trying to use them in other places.   It's best I should only post after a good night's sleep.  :)  Thanks for your assistance anyway.  I apologize for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it act like foreach and cause COM references we cannot release?

Yes, it will. Use the `for` loop with releasing statements in the code instead. It is not recommended to use LINQ, lambda expressions and etc. with Office RCW objects. Following that, you will not be able to release COM objects in a timely manner.

To understand how the `First` method works under the hood I'd suggest looking at the CIL (or MSIL) code generated by the .net framework compilers.